# Order by doesnt work with union, microsoft access database, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, union

I want to fetch data by percent from database based On rate field, also I want to show data randomly
so I tried this

```
string sql = "(SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 7 ORDER BY Rnd(-(1000*adID)*Time())) UNION (SELECT TOP 84 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 6 ORDER BY Rnd(-(1000*adID)*Time())) UNION (SELECT TOP 72 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 5 ORDER BY Rnd(-(1000*adID)*Time()))";
```

It shows correct data but not randomly,
any suggestion?

also I provided a sample for test purpose you can download from link below
http://www.4shared.com/zip/qMSYRglGce/testorderby.html

Comment: Does it work removing the union and the second select query?

Comment: yes this one lonely works: SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 7 ORDER BY Rnd(-(1000*adID)*Time())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an **UNION** query the **ORDER BY** should be applied to the whole set returned by the **UNION**
So you build a set of records from the three subselects then apply the order to the resulting set.

```
string sql =  @"SELECT * FROM 
                (
                   SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 7 
                     UNION 
                   SELECT TOP 84 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 6
                     UNION 
                   SELECT TOP 72 PERCENT * FROM tbl_adv WHERE Stars = 5
                )
                ORDER BY Rnd(-(1000*adID)*Time())";
```

Comment: I test it but it gives this error: The ORDER BY expression (Rnd(-(1000*adID)*Time())) includes fields that are not selected by the query. aslo I edited put a download link for sample project if frist post.